# internal logic from higher categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, higher-category-theory

nLab has an article on [internal logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic). Homotopy type theory also discusses its application in logic. Any one knows references to the correspondence study of the internal logic induced from higher category theories and higher topo theories ?

Comment: This adjunction between internal logic and the syntactic category was stablished only for presentable locally cartesian closed quasicategories. Take a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02648 and the references in the introduction. It's expected to hold without the presentability hypothesis, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the [reference](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02648) stated in the comment. nLab does provide an entry for [internal logic from $(\infty,1)-$topos.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic+of+an+(infinity,1)-topos)